# Salesforce Poller

Tags: rest-api

Is it possible to receive near real time records (can consider 1 min old records as near real time) using  [getUpdated](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_getupdated.htm) & [getDeleted](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_getdeleted.htm).

I don't want to use Streaming API.

I have done some test the data w.r.t to call is here, I have made a call to getUpdated and getDeleted at the time `2016-01-25T05:02:43.199-08:00`, 
startTime: `2016-01-25T01:02:00.000Z` EndTime: `2016-01-25T04:59:00.000Z`

I received latest date covered field as 
UpdateLatestDateCovered: `2016-01-25T01:02:00.000Z` DeleteLatestDateCovered: `2016-01-25T01:02:00.000Z`

Since the currentTime is way ahead then latest date covered, I have a doubt that near real time update of(1 min) is possible ?? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

I recently set this up for a client... I have used the below (obviously a little larger and more complex than this) to actually check if there is an update every 5 seconds using the actionPoller from there it checks to see if a record was modified in the last 6 seconds and refreshes only if it was.

VISUALFORCE:

```
  <!-- Action Poller to refresh the page every 5 seonds -->
  <!--<apex:actionPoller action="{! poller }" interval="5" reRender="functionArea" />-->
  <apex:actionPoller action="{! poller }" interval="5" rerender="all" rendered="{! refresh == 'true' }" oncomplete="refresh()" />
  <apex:actionPoller action="{! poller }" interval="5" rerender="functionArea" rendered="{! refresh == 'false' }"  />

 <!-- JS below just logs to the JS console if refresh is true or not -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
      console.log('{! refresh }');
  });
  </script>
```

APEX:

```
public class ControllerMethod {
    public Records__c r { get; set }

    public ControllerMethod(){
        copyOfControllerMethod();
    }

    public void copyOfControllerMethod(){
        getRecords();
    }

    public void getRecords(){
        r = [SELECT Id, LastModifiedDate FROM Records__c WHERE Id =: ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
    }

    public void poller(){
        // Retrieve all info again, you may need to move all methods from the main controller
        // method into a separate method that you are able to call to get all details again
        copyOfControllerMethod();

        // Set modified to -6 seconds instead of 5 just to ensure you do not miss anything
        DateTime modified = DateTime.now().addSeconds(-6);

        // Check to see if the Bucket Release has been modified
        if(r.LastModifiedDate > modified){
            // Set refresh to True and return to exit the code block
            refresh = 'true';
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks timothy for your answer, I am intersetd for getUpdated and getDeleted rest calls for polling not a SOQL based one